# QPushButton come out fended and I did not set that

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5, qpushbutton

I'm working in ubuntu kde 20.04, qt5.15
I my purpose was to create a QPushButton that change his color when he got clicked, then I created a new derived class for doing this (Facelet), it works but the colors I got are not those I was assuming to get.

Facelet.h

```
#ifndef FACELET_H
#define FACELET_H

#include <QPushButton>

class Facelet : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Facelet(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
    explicit Facelet(int color, QWidget *pareny = nullptr);

    void reset();

    static QString colors[6];

private slots:

    void __change_color();

private:
    int _ColorIndex;
};

#endif // FACELET_H
```

Facelet.cpp

```
#include "Facelet.h"

QString Facelet::colors[6] = { "background-color: yellow;", "background-color: red;", "background-color: green;", "background-color: rgb(255, 130, 50);", "background-color: blue;", "background-color: white;" };
enum { rxyellow, rxred, rxgreen, rxorange, rxblue, rxwhite };
//public

Facelet::Facelet(QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(parent),
    _ColorIndex(-1)
{
    this->resize(75, 75);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray");
    connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(__change_color()));
}

Facelet::Facelet(int color, QWidget* parent) :
    QPushButton(parent),
    _ColorIndex(color)
{
    this->resize(75, 75);
    this->setStyleSheet(colors[_ColorIndex]);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(__change_color()));
}

void Facelet::reset() {
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray");
}

//private

void Facelet::__change_color() {
    _ColorIndex = (_ColorIndex >= 5 ) ? 0 : (_ColorIndex + 1);
    this->setStyleSheet(colors[_ColorIndex]);
}
```

And here my main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "Facelet.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    Facelet f;
    w.setCentralWidget(&f);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

See? The screen is faded, I want a uniform strong color. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: try add `a.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: I added in the main, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

To correct that I found two solution via reimplementation od paintEvent method.
first

```
void Facelet::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setOpacity(1.0);
}
```

the first one is pretty easy, reading some topic I found out that a QWidget to have a `setStyleSheet(QString)` methods working properly need the following line in the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)` method as the official documentation says

```
void Facelet::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```